# Remove toolbar buttons programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I use CKEditor 4.5 and have a toolbar with a source code button. I can remove it in config.js with:

```
config.removeButtons = "Source";
```

But this is not what I want. I want to remove this button programmatically using my editor instance:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.replace("editorIdName");
```

I want to keep the values from `config.removeButtons` too.

**How can I remove a toolbar button programmatically?**

Comment: Check that : http://docs.cksource.com/CKEditor_3.x/Developers_Guide/Toolbar

Comment: But how do I do it after the editor has been initialized? Also I use CKEditor 4.5.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove the Source button for a particular instance, you can use the [in-page/per instance configuration method](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration-section-defining-configuration-in-page):

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editorIdName', {
   removeButtons: 'Source'
});
```

You can use this method to pass any configuration values to CKEditor instances.

Comment: When I do this I get the error: Uncaught The editor instance "CKEditor" is already attached to the provided element.

Comment: I want to keep the values from ``config.removeButtons`` too.